# Jackson Deserialize scala enum with integer value

Tags: scala, serialization, jackson

I am trying to deserialize a scala enumeration from integer value.

```
object TestEnum extends Enumeration {
  type TestEnum = Value
  val None = Value(0)
  val One = Value(1)
  val Two = Value(2)
  val Four = Value(4) // scalastyle:ignore

  @JsonCreator
  def forValue(value: Int): TestEnum = {
    TestEnum.Value(value)
  }
}

class TestEnum extends TypeReference[TestEnum.type]
```

When I try to deserialize this field, it throws an error as - `Cannot deserialize value of type` com.example.TestEnum$`from Integer value (token`JsonToken.VALUE_NUMBER_INT`)`

I see the jackson doc suggests to use the JsonCreator for the same in java, however nothing mentioned for scala enum.

I am using the defaultScalaMapper without any customization here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it with jsonCreator in the class using the enum. as follows -

```
class Example(testEnum: TestEnum) {
    @JsonCreator
    def this(testEnumNum: Int) = {
        this(TestEnum.forValue(testEnumNum))
    }
}
```

However I need to do this in every class, I was hoping if there can be a better solution for this.